# is it possible to accumulate None and Err in rust?

Tags: rust

I'm dealing with a depth structure in Rust coming from a library. It has a lot of Option and Result.

Is it possible to accumulate `Option`s and `Result`s and use the same error fn/message case None or Err?

I'm imagining something like the `?` in Javascript. Ex: `maybeExist1?.maybeExist2?.maybeExist3`

```rust
struct C {
    d: Option<()>,
}
struct B {
    c: Result<C, ()>,
}
struct A {
    b: Option<B>,
}
struct Test {
    a: Option<A>,
}

// How to safely access `d` from an instance of `Test`?
```

Comment: What do you mean by "accumulate"? javascript does not accumulate, it navigates through, Rust uses `map` or `and_then` depending on the exact case. If you have a sequence of results you could also [`partition`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-by-example/blob/master/src/error/iter_result.md#collect-all-valid-values-and-failures-with-partition) between successes and failures, though that's pretty rare, the more common use case is to [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#impl-FromIterator%3CResult%3CA,+E%3E%3E-for-Result%3CV,+E%3E) into a single failure if any.

Comment: Rust also has a ? operator, did you mean to use it?

Comment: In Javascript/Typescript, when a value has type `string | undefined` (string or undefined), I can use the ? to safely go down through the object.  

I'm looking for something similar in Rust.

Comment: I just added an example of something that the library returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust does have `?`, but it can only return early when the `Try` type it's used on has the same type as the current function’s return type. You cannot automatically mix `Option` and `Result`. (Note that in the case of JavaScript, basically everything is an `Option` and there is no `Result`, so `?` “just works”.) To get around this, there are methods that go between and `Option` and `Result`. You can use these to turn `Ok` into `Some` and `Err` into `None`, or vice versa.

```rust
struct C {
    d: Option<i32>,
}
struct B {
    c: Result<C, &'static str>,
}
struct A {
    b: Option<B>,
}
struct Test {
    a: Option<A>,
}

fn get_d_opt(x: Test) -> Option<i32> {
    x.a?.b?.c.ok()?.d
}

fn get_d_result(x: Test) -> Result<i32, &'static str> {
    x.a.ok_or("no a")?.b.ok_or("no b")?.c?.d.ok_or("no d")
}
```

Eventually you'll be able to use these in any block at all, not just a function, once [`try` blocks land](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31436).

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify what should happen if the value can not be accessed.
Should a default be returned or maybe `None`?

I thought `None` might be better suited, so here is a way to access the nested structure field returning `None` if either an error or `None` is encountered on any level:

```rust
struct C {
    d: Option<()>,
}
struct B {
    c: Result<C, ()>,
}
struct A {
    b: Option<B>,
}
struct Test {
    a: Option<A>,
}

fn main() {
    let test1 = Test {
        a: Some(A {
            b: Some(B {
                c: Ok(C { d: Some(()) }),
            }),
        }),
    };

    let value1: Option<()> = test1.a.and_then(|a| a.b.and_then(|b| b.c.map_or(None, |c| c.d)));

    let test2 = Test {
        a: Some(A {
            b: None
        }),
    };

    let value2: Option<()> = test2.a.and_then(|a| a.b.and_then(|b| b.c.map_or(None, |c| c.d)));

    println!("{:?}", value1); // Prints: Some(())
    println!("{:?}", value2); // Prints: None
}
```